# Cómo asignar un evento a un botón en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando asignar un evento a un botón y no sé por qué razón no me lo detecta.

Mi código:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">

        #un_div{

            background-color: red;
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }

        #un_divv{

            background-color: green;
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            display: none;
        }
        </style>
        <script>

            document.getElementById('enviar').addEventListener("click", pulsar, false);

            function pulsar(){

                var div1=document.getElementById("un_div");
                var div2=document.getElementById("un_divv");

                div1.style.display="none"
                div2.style,display="";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="un_div"></div>
            <div id="un_divv"></div>
            <input type="button" id="pulsar" name="pulsar" value="pulsa!" />
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: ¿qué intentaste? muestra parte de tu proceso de solución del error para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: el id del boton es "pulsar"  no "enviar"

Comment: Pues estoy intentando que al pulsar el botón se cambien la propiedades display de los divs que tengo. Probé poniendo un alert para ver de qué podía ser el fallo y directamente es que no entra en la función. El id sería de tantas veces que probé cosas distintas, aunque ponga "pulsar", sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Por favor, dale a [edit] para incluir los datos. En comentarios se ven menos y peor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pon el `<script>` **después** del resto de los elementos de la página.

Para los *script*s *en-línea*, se ejecutan **en estricto orden secuencial**, según el navegador los va encontrando; en tu caso, el código se ejecuta **antes** de que el navegador conozca lo que es `pulsar`.

Answer (score 1):

Mira aquí en está línea podría estár el error, la verdad no veo más con lo que enviaste.

`div2.style,display="";`

Tienes una coma, en vez de un punto.